# Return result from one table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have two tables:

```
users
{ id, username }

items
{ id, user_id }
```

In laravel, how would I appropriately return the username on an items permalink?

For example:

```
item #39 by JohnSmith
```

I tried the following:

```
$items = DB::table('items')->where('id', '=', 39)->first();
$username DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $items->user_id)->first();

item #{{ $items->id }} by {{ $username }}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it. If not, what output are you getting? Note that you're missing an equals character `=` in the second line - I'm assuming that's a typo here and not in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two models in your `models` directory:

```
// User Model (app/models/User.php)
class User Extends Eloquent {
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Item');
    }
}

// Item Model (app/models/Item.php)
class Item Extends Eloquent {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Now you may use in your controller, something like this:

```
$item = Item::with('user')->find(39);
$username = $item->user->username;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eloquent Models you could simply do

```
$item = Item::find(39);
$username = $item->user->username;
```

This of course requires you to have your relationships defined properly in both the User and Item model.